# Bootstrap 3 - Re-ordering 2 column layout for mobile (content not vertically aligned)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a quick demo of the problem I'm having here: http://www.bootply.com/Nb2PUnwINT

The behaviour for small screens and below is perfect here, but on medium/large screens the yellow column I want to be along side the green one.

Is this possible? Hopefully I've provided enough detail here.

Comment: You could try using http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ ... You cannot have the yellow alongside the green if you want the red to stay where it is also (using only native bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">

           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:green">
                Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque porta felis a ex egestas ultrices. Duis vel lorem nulla. Vestibulum eget risus nec felis hendrerit aliquet. Sed et tempus tellus. Curabitur congue magna lacus, facilisis rhoncus neque finibus hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                Nunc sed viverra nunc. Ut venenatis dapibus odio vel viverra. Nullam sem justo, scelerisque et fringilla quis, ullamcorper id diam. Suspendisse vitae justo porta, molestie diam vitae, pulvinar nunc. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ut felis lacus. Etiam quis pretium dolor. Nulla eu rutrum erat. Ut hendrerit et diam ac eleifend. Suspendisse mollis elit lorem, ultrices fermentum erat convallis mattis. Duis congue mattis magna non elementum. Ut ultricies vitae ante sit amet tempor.
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:red">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:yellow">
                met, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget odio ut lectus dignissim varius. Praesent volutpat, dui quis ultricies pellentesque, sem ipsum volutpat libero, in fermentum leo nisl a orci. Praesent gravida elit ac felis interdum, at elementum lacus tristique. Curabitur dignissim metus tristique vehicula iaculis. Quisque mattis tincidunt tellus, et aliquet arcu aliquet ut. Vestibulum vel metus nec ipsum sagittis aliquet in sit amet erat. Praesent pellentesque sit amet massa sed lobortis. Proin blandit consectetur egestas. Nulla cursus tortor turpis, nec tempor metus viverra et. Quisque id auctor arcu, ac posuere eros. Curabitur ac tincidunt purus. Integer scelerisque quis ex vitae volutpat. Donec non pretium turpis.
                Duis dolor felis, convallis non venenatis ut, vulputate in ipsum. Etiam nisi tortor, finibus sit amet tellus non, bibendum sollicitudin enim. Proin in mollis neque, id faucibus felis. Proin cursus tristique mollis. Proin eget aliquam orci. Suspendisse egestas consequat magna quis ornare. Duis maximus dui sit amet neque fermentum aliquam.
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: On smaller devices, I want the red background to be above the green which is why I didn't do something like that to begin with.